# I am using wp_nav_menu & strip_tags to output my WP menu but I want to use CSS classes as well

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am having some trouble with my Wordpress menu. I am using the wp_nav_menu function to generate the menu and the strip_tags function to remove the list tags from my navigation links. With those two functions I have not been able to figure out how to how to wrap the navigation links in a CSS class.

My code outputs like this:

```
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

Using the following php:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'menu' => 'main-menu',
        'echo' => false 
    );

    echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu($args),'<a>');
?>
```

However, I want it to output like this:

```
<a class= "w-nav-link nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
```

What should I do differently?

Comment: Use jquery to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_replace before you echo:

```
 $args = array(
    'menu' => 'main-menu',
    'echo' => false                  
    );
 $output = strip_tags(wp_nav_menu($args),'<a>');
 $output = preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="w-nav-link nav-link"', $output); // Apply class to each anchor tag
 echo $output;
```